# How to reset/reinitilize Ubuntu bridge

Tags: networking, server, network-bridge

I have workable Bridge in Ubuntu 21.10 used by VM

[image]

This is definition of my Bridge.

```
#cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml

network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp4s0:
      addresses:
        - 144.XX.XX.107/32
        - 2a01:XXX.XXX:546a::2/64
      routes:
        - on-link: true
          to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 144.XX.XX.97
      gateway6: fe90::1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 1.1.1.1
    vlan.4005:
      id: 4005
      link: enp4s0
      addresses: [157.XX.XX.64/27]
      mtu: 1400
  bridges:
    br2:
      mtu: 1400
      addresses: [157.XX.XX.64/27]
      interfaces: [vlan.4005]
```

Unfortunately, this is production server and I have no option to reboot it. However I see issue in one of Bridge port (#18). Any other Bridge ports working fine. VM connected to port #18 has the same IP tuning as each other (incude route), that VM can see any other VM in this Bridge, but it has not internet, VLAN gateway is not ping from port #18.

I can transfer IP from that VM to another VM and IP will be working and accessible from inet. I try to reinstall many times VM connected to port 18, but failed.  I believe port #18 in my Bridge is broken for something reason. I can no opportunity to reboot server, but I can disconnect server from internet, reboot Bridge (HOW EXACTLY?) or reboot/reinstall VM connected to port #18.

How to reboot/reinitialize Ubuntu Bridge ?

Answer (score 1):

You have reached the MAC limit with your current configuration on our side. It is only allow to communicate with 32 MAC per switch-port. You have to reduce this count or change the internal routing configuration.

Kind regards,
Hetzner support